# Can Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> return null? How?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm investigating a `NullReferenceException` I cannot reproduce locally, and I need to rule out `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` as a potential source of null. When I try it locally with some invalid input, it always throws an exception and never returns null. My code assumes if it doesn't throw an exception, it returns a non-null object.
The [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm) doesn't state it either way.

The version is `4.5.11` if that is relevant.

Comment: Even if it wasn't [open source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json), it's .NET, so ILSpy could find out. Digging into that is a bit of work, but I don't see why you'd trust a random stranger if they said "definitely not" -- even if that stranger was the developer themselves, since anyone can make a mistake. You should invest in getting a dump or at the very least a stack trace of the exception so you can see where the problem *is* (possibly with extra assertions sprinkled in the code), since debugging by eliminating the places at which it's *not* is an extremely tedious process.

Comment: @JeroenMostert The question as I understand it is whether there are examples of circumstances under which Newtonsoft deserialization will return `null`. (It turns out one such case is if you feed it the empty string, which is actually a plausible thing to happen in code). I think that this is a reasonable question that's potentially useful to future readers (especially given how common that library is).

Comment: @EJoshuaS: I don't think the question is unreasonable -- if I thought that, I'd have downvoted it. (I wasn't one of the people that did.) It's lucky that you could quickly come up with an example, and it would be even luckier if those circumstances are actually what caused the NRE in the code, but my comment was for the "if your question *doesn't* get a positive answer, here's what's likely to get you results faster than waiting for one" circumstance, which I happened to consider more likely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can. Here's an example of code that does that:

```
namespace x {
    public class Something
    {
        public string abc { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Something newtonsoft = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Something>("");
    }
}
```

Tested with Newtonsoft 11.0.1, .NET 4.6.1, and Visual Studio Professional 2015 by the way.

Comment: Ok, same on 4.5.11. Thanks!